# Redis pipe mode throw client reached max query buffer length?

Tags: redis

I'm trying to import about 3GB neo4j cypher script data into redis, using the redis pipe mode.
docker image:

> redislabs/redisgraph:2.8.17

redis version:

> Redis server v=6.2.6 sha=00000000:0 malloc=jemalloc-5.1.0 bits=64 build=e15697f1a083b6bc

redisGraph module doc: [redis-graph-doc](https://redis.io/docs/stack/graph/)

I refer to the following documents and use python scripts to generate data that conforms to the redis protocol

[redis-bulk-loading-doc](https://redis.io/docs/reference/patterns/bulk-loading/)

data example:

`cat -A redis_command.txt | head`

```
*3^M$
$11^M$
GRAPH.QUERY^M$
$9^M$
knowledge^M$
$280^M$
MERGE (n:xxxx) SET n.name="xxx", n.nebula_id="xxx", n.concept_id="xxx", n.create_time="xxx", n.data_source="xxx", n.entity_tag="xxx", n.version="xxx"^M$
^M$
*3^M$
$11^M$
GRAPH.QUERY^M$
$9^M$
knowledge^M$
$270^M$
MERGE (n:xxxx) SET n.name="xxx", n.nebula_id="xxx", n.concept_id="xxx", n.create_time="xxx", n.data_source="xxx", n.entity_tag="xxx", n.version="xxx"^M$
```

After that I use the following command for data import

> cat redis_command.txt | redis-cli --pipe

But the command runs for about 1 minute, and it will automatically exit.

Only this information is printed in the log file of redis

> Closing client that reached max query buffer length: id=10084 addr=127.0.0.1:34990 laddr=127.0.0.1:6379 fd=11 name= age=47 idle=0 flags=b db=0 sub=0 psub=0 multi=-1 qbuf=1073756036 qbuf-free=268421234 argv-mem=293 obl=0 oll=0 omem=0 tot-mem=1342198077 events=r cmd=graph.QUERY user=default redir=-1 (qbuf initial bytes: "\r\n*3\r\n$11\r\nGRAPH.QUERY\r\n$9\r\nknowledge\r\n$274\r\nMERGE (n:`xxxxxxxxx")

I don't know where the problem is, how should I solve this problem?

Comment: I believe you've overflowed the client (you connection to Redis) commands buffer by sending too much data on the connection, when piping Redis accumulates all of the commands in an internal buffer, upon sending `EXEC` Redis will executes all of the buffered commands.

I would suggest trying to use either `redisgraph bulk loader` or `redisgraph bulk update`
As these send the data in chunks.

Generally speaking try to avoid piping large quantities of data via `Redis-cli`

Comment: In the end, this problem was not solved, but I used the python library provided by redisgraph to complete the final import purpose in a very simple way of multi-process writing, and the speed met my needs (20K per second)